# How to query a custom post type with a taxonomy filter but display post type archive page?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, query, jigoshop, request-filter

I'm filtering the main query of Jigoshop with my own taxonomy with this hook ([The file responsible for Jigoshop queries that I'm hooking, Jigoshop hooks onto WP 'request' filter](https://github.com/jigoshop/jigoshop/blob/dev/classes/jigoshop_query.class.php)):

```
add_filter( 'loop_shop_tax_query', 'my_loop_shop_tax_query', 11 );
function loop_shop_tax_query( $request )
{
    $region = 'dublin';
    if ( ! empty( $region ) ) {
        $request[] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'product_region',
            'field'     => 'slug',
            'terms'     => $region,
            'operator'  => 'IN',
        );
    }

    return $request;
}
```

I want to filter every Jigoshop query this way (all products display, category display & search display). This is working as intended but wp_title() in the html head is causing the error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$labels in /var/www/wp/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 658

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/wp/wp-includes/general-template.php on line 658
```

I've tracked this down in general-template.php and `is_post_type_archive()` is returning true even though `get_tax()` is also returning true. `get_queried_object()` is returning my taxonomy object (normally the Jigoshop product custom post type object).

I need `get_queried_object()` to still return the Jigoshop product custom post type object and `get_tax()` should return false, I want to filter the posts with my taxonomy but I want to keep displaying a post type archive (is this even possible?)

Just before the request is sent back to WP for 'request' filter, it looks like this:

```
Array ( [post_type] => product [post_status] => publish [posts_per_page] => 12 [orderby] => post_date [order] => asc [tax_query] => Array ( [relation] => AND [0] => Array ( [taxonomy] => product_region [field] => slug [terms] => dublin [operator] => IN ) ) [meta_query] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => visibility [value] => Array ( [0] => visible [1] => catalog ) [compare] => IN ) ) [post__in] => Array ( [0] => 293 [1] => 291 [2] => 289 [3] => 18 [4] => 0 ) )
```

I hope this isn't too specific and makes sense, I'm really at my wit's end here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is, in all honesty, to hook into `wp_title` and change things, and just be aware that the warnings are there but not showing in production (because you've property configured your server).

What follows is a kind of hacky solution.

If you take a look at `get_queried_object`...

```
<?php
function get_queried_object() {
    global $wp_query;
    return $wp_query->get_queried_object();
}
```

Just a thin wrapper around `WP_Query::get_queried_object`, so let's take a look at that.

```
<?php
function get_queried_object() {
    if ( isset($this->queried_object) )
        return $this->queried_object;

    $this->queried_object = null;
    $this->queried_object_id = 0;

    if ( $this->is_category || $this->is_tag || $this->is_tax ) {
        $tax_query_in_and = wp_list_filter( $this->tax_query->queries, array( 'operator' => 'NOT IN' ), 'NOT' );

        $query = reset( $tax_query_in_and );

        if ( 'term_id' == $query['field'] )
            $term = get_term( reset( $query['terms'] ), $query['taxonomy'] );
        elseif ( $query['terms'] )
            $term = get_term_by( $query['field'], reset( $query['terms'] ), $query['taxonomy'] );

        if ( ! empty( $term ) && ! is_wp_error( $term ) )  {
            $this->queried_object = $term;
            $this->queried_object_id = (int) $term->term_id;

            if ( $this->is_category )
                _make_cat_compat( $this->queried_object );
        }
    } elseif ( $this->is_post_type_archive ) {
        $this->queried_object = get_post_type_object( $this->get('post_type') );
    } elseif ( $this->is_posts_page ) {
        $page_for_posts = get_option('page_for_posts');
        $this->queried_object = get_post( $page_for_posts );
        $this->queried_object_id = (int) $this->queried_object->ID;
    } elseif ( $this->is_singular && !is_null($this->post) ) {
        $this->queried_object = $this->post;
        $this->queried_object_id = (int) $this->post->ID;
    } elseif ( $this->is_author ) {
        $this->queried_object_id = (int) $this->get('author');
        $this->queried_object = get_userdata( $this->queried_object_id );
    }

    return $this->queried_object;
}
```

As you can see, WordPress checks a bunch of stuff to see just what type of query this is and where it's set. The first check is to see if this is a category, tag, or taxonomy archive. Since that succeeds, the post type archive object is never set.

What's really weird is why both `is_post_type_archive` and `is_tax` are returning true.  Due to the way `WP_Query::parse_query` works, it's possible that an archive can be both a post type archive as well as a taxonomy archive.

Anyway, `WP_Query::$queried_object` is a public property, do just hook into someplace before `wp_title` fires and replace it.  `template_redirect` would work.

This is very much a hack, but there's no `pre_wp_title` filter or the like where you could prevent the warnings. Untested example below. Be aware that if the WP core decides to make `$queried_object` a private or protected property in future release this will not work.  It could also negatively impact other areas of your site.

```
<?php
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse87222_change_object');
function wpse87222_change_object()
{
    global $wp_the_query;

    // check for post type archive
    if (is_post_type_archive('product')) {
        $wp_the_query->queried_object = get_post_type_object('product');
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer Chris but I ended up hooking `'loop-shop-posts-in'` in the Jigo query and using `get_posts` to get the ID's of every product with my tax query. Jigo then uses these ID's with `'post__in'` for their main query which produces exactly what I want. It's an extra database call but it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: You should post your solution and mark that as accepted, not mine! Folks down the line will likely have a similar question, tell them how you really solved it.